# Nginx proxy manager, how to forward to a specific folder?

Tags: nginx, networking, domain-name-system

I've got a few things running behind [nginx proxy manager](https://nginxproxymanager.com/) and they all work because the basic http(s)://IP:port request locally auto loads the desired location. For example, my nextcloud instance loads /index.php/login.

I just installed an app ([Azuracast](https://www.azuracast.com/), using docker), but the way that works is http(s)://x.x.x.x:port loads /login or /dashboard if you are logged in. Thats the admin dashboard but I am trying to expose the "public" page which is:

http(s)://x.x.x.x:port/public/stationName

And the port is the same for the management dashboard.

Anyone know how to accomplish that with nginx proxy manager? When trying to use the custom locations setting I still just get directed to the main management page. nginx conf here https://pastebin.com/raw/rKM6kB3F

If not possible with nginx proxy manager is there a way to accomplish this otherwise, while my main domain is forwarded to the nignx proxy manager server through my firewall?

Edit:

I have this a little further along, and can get the page to load now after reading [This comment](https://github.com/jc21/nginx-proxy-manager/issues/671#issuecomment-721198949/671#issuecomment-721198949)  and adding:

```
location = /{return 301 $scheme://$http_host/public/stationName/;}
```

to "custom nginx configuration" under advanced in nginx proxy manager.

The public page loads, I can see the station and progress bar for the playing son, but media seems to be blocked. No sound or album art. Getting a Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG when trying to load the album art at least, no idea about sound.